# Message part request was not recognized

Tags: web-services

I have developed a Webservice . It was working fine with SOAP UI
When the client tested it through APIGEE , it started giving

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
        <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Message part request was not recognized.  (Does it exist in service WSDL?)</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Could anybody please tell me what might cause this ??

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, I got to this page googling for facing the same issue, the only answer I have found is here: http://prystash.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/wsdls-and-message-parts-not-recognized.html, quoting:

> The element declaration contained a reference to a complexType
>   instead of having the complexType defined within, or as part of, the
>   element declaration.

Comment: I have element declared with complexType within but get same error `<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://TargetNamespace.com/FB1" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://TargetNamespace.com/FB1">
  <xsd:element name="items">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="item" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="price" type="xsd:decimal"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>`